# image not saving to db edit profile django

Tags: django

Hi i have a registration form which contains username and email fields.After the registration is done,the user has an option to edit his profile which contains username,email and two other fields dob and photo(profile picture)..after clicking on the submit button all the fields are stored to the db except photo field.I checked the db the 'photo' column is empty. When i click on 'edit profile' for the second time i am getting data for all fields except photo. Can someone tell me why the photo fields is not stored to the db?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you forgot to add `enctype` atrribute to `<form>` tag.  It should be like this:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   ...
</form>
```

Another possible reason is initiating of form instance without `request.FILES` argument. Correct form creation is:

```
form = MyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: My editprofile.html file looks like this                         <form method="post" action="/">
           {% csrf_token %}
           {{ form.as_p }}
           <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
          </form>                                                                 Now where  should i write this? enctype="multipart/form-data"??

Comment: Change first line of your template to `<form method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: Still it is not getting stored to db, when i remove blank=True in my photo field,in my edit profile after entering details when i click on submit it is asking "this field is required" for photo field as it is not getting stored

Comment: I added another possible reason of the problem to the answer. Check it.